# Joe's own editor - how to change the tab size

Tags: editor, joe-editor

I'm having trouble changing the tab size in Joe.

I have copied `joerc` to `$HOME` and have edited the `-tab` line to `-tab 4` but this hasn't changed the option in Joe. Also the number 4 is green instead of blue when I edit `joerc` so I think its reading it wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've wasted about 20 mins trying to set tab size too. Here is the solution:

I. Open:

`/etc/joe/joerc`

II. Find row containing -tab nnn and change it to:

`-tab 4`

(I assume that you want to change tab size to 4. If you want different value, please replace all the 4s with your value)

III. Find -istep nnn and change it to:

`-istep 4`

IV. Save & exit

This will set tab size 4 for files WITHOUT extension. If you want to change tab size for files with common extensions like *.java:

I. open /etc/joe/ftyperc

II. Find your extension, for example *.java. Initially it looks like:

```
 JAVA

*.java

-autoindent

-syntax java

-smarthome

-smartbacks

-purify

-cpara >#!;*/%
```

III. You have to comment (insert tab before it) -autoindent and add -istep 4 bellow -cpara. It should look like:

```
 JAVA

*.java

     -autoindent

-syntax java

-smarthome

-smartbacks

-purify

-cpara >#!;*/%

-istep 4
```

Answer (score 12):

The real solution is:

1. Create a file `$HOME/.joerc` (NOT `.joe` as at least the Debian `joerc` suggests!)
2. FIRST LINE must be `:include /etc/joe/joerc`
3. Then, a line containing just a `*` and a newline character
4. Then, `-tab 4` and `-istep 4`, each on a single line.
5. Add a blank line at the end.

You may also add further options with other masks.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: +1. As of October 2016 with Joe v4.1 and 4.2 tab position only seems to be honored if the `:include /etc/joe/joerc` line is moved to the end of the `$HOME/.joerc` file.  The joe user manual says to copy /etc/joe/joerc to your home directory and modify it but I think the `:include` method listed here is more manageable.

Comment: Why do I lose context highlighting when I do it this way?

Comment: I'm so lost. So what's the 2020 answer?

Comment: @dylanh724 wrote "I'm so lost. So what's the 2020 answer?". [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65925491/2660408) has just been added, maybe it's useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, I am running an ancient version of joe on AIX and after some painful trial and error it turned out that -smartbacks was the problem for me.  I commented that line out and tabs work, put it back and they go back to 2.  Probably fixed in a later version, but hopefully this helps someone else with the same problem.

```
 JAVA
*.java
-spaces
-tab 4
-istep 4
-indentc 32
-autoindent
-syntax java
-smarthome
 -smartbacks
-purify
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time the tab key is pressed (using joe 4.6) it inserts 4 spaces after having followed those steps:

- Execute `sudo joe /etc/joe/joerc`
- Find the row containing `-tab nnn        Tab width`, change it to `-tab 4         Tab width` and make sure that there is no whitespace at its left side.
- A few lines down, find the row containing `-spaces                 TAB inserts spaces instead of tabs` and make sure that there is no whitespace at its left side.
- Save and exit

This works here for files without extension, for .cpp files, for .java files, for .c files, for .txt files, etc.